# PlayFramework JPA find on two columns

Tags: jpa, find, playframework

I was trying to query by Person and Event like this :

```java
static void setProfile(Event event, Person person) {
    Register register = Register.find("byEventPerson", event, person).first();
}
```

but I get

> IllegalArgumentException occured :
>   org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of
>   declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are
>   1-based! Position: 2

Comment: How are events and person declared in your Register entity? Have you tried with Register.find("Event = ? and Person = ?", event, person);

Answer (score 3):

Yes, query expects one parameters, you are giving two. You have to add the **And** :

```
Register.find("byEventAndPerson", event, person).first();
```